# Jenkins GitHub pull request builder - get branch name for execute shell

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, ghprb

I am using Jenkins [GitHub pull request builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) plugin for running my unit tests when a pull request is made vis a vis a web hook. For the build step, I need to know the name of the branch that is being merged in (e.g. I need develop branch if merging that into master branch). Is there a way to get access to this in the Jenkins execute shell? Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your link has the answer:

> The plugin makes some very useful environment variables available.
>
> 1. ghprbActualCommit
> 2. ghprbActualCommitAuthor
> 3. ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail
> 4. ghprbPullDescription
> 5. ghprbPullId
> 6. ghprbPullLink
> 7. ghprbPullTitle
> 8. ghprbSourceBranch
> 9. ghprbTargetBranch
> 10. sha1

You'll want to use `$ghprbSourceBranch` to get the value of the branch being built somewhere else in your script.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Branch Specifier", enter `${sha1}`.