# In a Github PR, how to get the targeted branch name?

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, target, pull-request

Is there a command to know the **targeted branch name** of a PR when building this PR?

Context:
I am building some code with a "Multibranch Pipeline" jenkins job.
When I create a Github Pull request, this job is triggered and I would like to know, in this job execution, what is the targeted branch name of this PR.

I have tried different commands in my Jenkinsfile but none are giving me the expected result.

If I try this: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
it gives me: `HEAD`

If a execute: `git branch`
I get: `* (HEAD detached at 464f73c0)`

What I want to get is, for instance, `master` if the PR is targeting master as destination branch.

Any idea ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are doing this in Jenkins and building a PR. The target branch name should be in some environment variable. Check the documentation of Jenkins or it's plugin getting used for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins GitHub pull request builder - get branch name for execute shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926515/jenkins-github-pull-request-builder-get-branch-name-for-execute-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Vishwanath's idea I was able to find the answer:

In jenkins "Multibranch Pipeline" jobs, when building a PR, the targeted branch is available as an environment variable: `CHANGE_TARGET`

Comment: This document might be helpful when you are using Jenkins with Bitbucket [Environment variables for Bitbucket Branch Source plugin](https://docs.mohami.io/webhook-to-jenkins-for-bitbucket/environment-variables-for-bitbucket-branch-source-)